# How should Open-Telemetry users prevent accidentally creating attributes with matching keys?

Tags: open-telemetry

I'm looking at using Open-Telemetry (https://opentelemetry.io/docs/) for a new logging backend, but want to be sure that I (or other users) don't create `AttributeKey` instances which accidentally duplicate keys from another library. Unfortunately however, I cannot find a discussion on best-practice for choosing key names.

I appears as if `Attributes` and `AttributesBuilder` are designed to represent a single-valued map (even though values can be lists, they must have values of the same type), and that a key is unique according to its 'key' and 'type' values.

See:
https://javadoc.io/static/io.opentelemetry/opentelemetry-api/1.22.0/io/opentelemetry/api/common/Attributes.html

This creates a risk that eventually two libraries will both create a key such as `longKey("user_id")`, which feels like it would be bad (especially if the end user cannot modify either library).

https://javadoc.io/static/io.opentelemetry/opentelemetry-api/1.22.0/io/opentelemetry/api/common/AttributeKey.html#longKey(java.lang.String)

To be a "good citizen", should I be prefixing key strings with the the originating package/class name, or similar? If so, is there a doc link to explain this which I can reference in my code?

I'd also like to know if there are syntax limitations on key strings (e.g. not allowing newlines or '/' etc.).

EDIT:
Looking at the code (`ArrayBackedAttributes` & `ImmutableKeyValuePairs`), I've also noticed an issue whereby the default Attributes implementation seemingly deliberately ignores the "type" when deduplicating.

This means that if two keys with the same key-string but different types exist, one of them will appear to be silently removed from the resulting `Attributes` instance, rather than replaced (since the `get()` method uses the `AttributeKey#equals()` method which *does* check for type). So it's not even "last one wins" in terms of the external behavior (which is what the code suggests it is trying to achieve).

```java
AttributeKey<String> strKey = AttributeKey.stringKey("foo");
AttributeKey<Boolean> boolKey = AttributeKey.booleanKey("foo");

Attributes attr = Attributes.builder()
    .put(strKey, "String")
    .put(boolKey, true)
    .build();

System.out.println("value=" + attr.get(strKey));
```

Results in `value=null` and not `value=true` !?

Can someone explain the precise expected semantics for "duplicate" keys and how to best avoid them (esp. if writing a shared library)?

Answer (score 0):

> To be a "good citizen", should I be prefixing key strings with the the originating package/class name, or similar? If so, is there a doc link to explain this which I can reference in my code?

The [attribute naming](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-specification/blob/main/specification/common/attribute-naming.md) document from the specification says that attribute keys SHOULD use namespacees to avoid collisions. So yes, adding prefix (we call it a namespace), to the attribute is recommended.

> I'd also like to know if there are syntax limitations on key strings (e.g. not allowing newlines or '/' etc.).

The same document recommends that attribute names be limited to printable basic latin characters, referencing [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Latin_(Unicode_block)#Table_of_characters).

As for your last point about attribute key collisions, they should have last win semantics. I've opened [this issue](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/issues/5920) in `opentelemetry-java` to track discuss the issue / fix more.